# Jquery - Works with Chaining but not apart

Tags: jquery, jquery-chaining

I'm an experienced developer who is new to Jquery.  I'm running into a problem where I have code that works when it chained together but not when it is separate and I would like to understand Jquery behavior.

I have a `<div>` with 4 buttons in it.  When one of the 4 buttons is pressed, I need all 4 buttons to go away and a new button to replace it (the new button is a button with the same value as the one pressed but with different CSS to make it look different)

When the button is pressed I clear the `<div>` out like this

```
$(this).parent().empty();
```

I then build up the new button I want to insert

```
var splitstr = event.target.id.split('-');
var pick = splitstr[0];
var position_id = splitstr[1];
var singlebutton = '<button class="pick' + pick + ' pickbutton-box btn btn-primary btn-large madepick" name="pick" ' + 'id="made'+ position_id + '" ' + 'value="' + pick + '">' + pick + '</button>';
```

and then I tried to insert it back into the parent:

```
$(this).parent().append(singlebutton);
```

When I do this all 4 of the buttons in the `<div>` are removed but the new button is not added.  However, if I build the string up before I do the empty and append

```
var singlebutton = " ---- HTML CODE for button ---- "
$(this).parent().empty().append(singlebutton);
```

Everything works as expected.  This doesn't seem to make any sense to me.  Can someone please explain what is happening.

Comment: Instead of saying HTML CODE for button could you show your actual code? There's a chance that may be causing your issue.

Comment: I suspect your `this` value will become `undefined` right after `.empty()` on the separate lines version. Could you test that and confirm?

Comment: Mike Robinson - Added code as requested.  Basically I grab the ID which comprises a pick and another ID which I will need later.  I break that up and then reform the button.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You state you have something like this:

```
<div>
    <button>click me</button>
    <button>click me</button>
    <button>click me</button>
    <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

And an event handler like this:

```
$('div button').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().empty();
   // etc
});
```

When your handler code runs, `this` points to the clicked button, which is removed by `$(this).parent().empty();`. You'd need to save a reference to the parent div to be able to reference it later, because `this` will become empty. Something like this:

```
$('div button').click(function() {
   var div = $(this).parent().empty();
   // cannot use 'this' anymore below this point
   div.append('something');
});
```

The chained version works because a reference to the parent element is what is passed ahead starting from `.parent`, and the value of `this` becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks.  Seeing you explain it this way makes perfect sense.  Not sure why I didn't understand that before.  the $(this) is obviously removed when I did an empty because I "removed" it from the parent and thus the reference to it.